# Using Robolectric with an Application class

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-testing

I am getting started with using Robolectric for testing my android app. A bit of context, my app is already built and the repo is fairly large.

I setup my IDE as instructed in the Robolectric documentation [here](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/). But trying to run the tests, I ended up with errors in my application class. 
It complains that some or the other dependency is missing or running into weird states which I can't explain.(Not a great start I guess).

Is there a way, I can basically mock the application class or have a dummy application class ? 
I tried to find examples but it's not clear, where I am supposed to specify the class. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you have? Why do you want to mock application class?

Comment: Can you please point me to an example that does this ?
The app that I am working with is throwing exceptions that the service is null, it expects the network to return with tokens and multiple things.

Comment: Can you share your code? Here is example of my project https://github.com/emartynov/android-template-project

Comment: unfortunately cannot share the code. I ended up creating a mock application class and that seemed to have solved my problems.